# Android Application crashes, using Unity and Vuforia

Tags: android, crash, unity-game-engine, vuforia, assetbundle

first of all thank you for taking your time reading my Problem.
I'm using Unity Pro 4.2.0f and a Nexus 10.

The Problem is the following:
My Application crashes after I loaded and unloaded +/- 20 Asset Bundles.
Of course my first thought was that it could be a Memory Problem, that maybe some stuff isn't getting unloaded properly but I checked everything with the profiler and I tried to encode the Logcat but I can't get the problem fixed.

This are the two Logcat lines where the APP crashes:

`E/Surface (  123): queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -32
I/ActivityManager(  450): Process com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx (pid 21277) has died.`

It is never happening on the PC in the PlayMode...

Has anybody an Idea what could be the Problem, or how I could go on to find a solution.

Thank you.

Greetings 
Patric

Comment: `#01  pc 003c9b38  /data/app-lib/com.xx.xx-1/libunity.so (std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, stl_allocator<char, (MemLabelIdentifier)45, 16> >::operator=(char const*)+20)

I/DEBUG   (  179):     #02  pc 003ca314  /data/app-lib/com.xx.xx-1/libunity.so (MemoryProfiler::RegisterRootAllocation(void*, BaseAllocator*, char const*, char const*)+108)

I/DEBUG   (  179):     #03  pc 000b2958  /data/app-lib/com.xx.xx-1/libunity.so (set_root_allocation(void*, MemLabelId, char const*, char const*)+72)`

Comment: `I/DEBUG   (  179):     #04  pc 001e0454  /data/app-lib/com.xx.xx-1/libunity.so (WWW::FeedUnityWebStream(bool)+480) 

I/DEBUG   (  179):     #05  pc 004b4d34  /data/app-lib/com.xx.xx-1/libunity.so (AndroidWWW::ReadCallback(void*, void*, int, void*, int)+200)`

this are more or less the most important stacktraces of the logcat